# Cannot read Match property of undefined - cant find function

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a jQuery plugin that changes the wid parameter within the URL through regex.

However, there is an initial function resizeMethod which fires but it has a dependency on another function to replace the url.

This is currently throwing out an error message:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined**

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jagmitg/bq3oov2e/

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.resizeImage = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
      sizing: 1,
      methodName: 'src',
      regex: /wid=\d+(\.\d)*/g,
      imageSize: [2000, 1824, 1024, 767, 480]
    };

    var _se = $.extend(defaults, options);

    var $el = this,

      resizeMethod = function() {
        var src = $el.attr(_se.methodName),
          currentWidth,
          newWidth,
          newSrc = {};

        if ($(window).width() > 1824) {
          sizingMethod(src, _se.regex, currentWidth, newWidth, newSrc, Math.round(1824 / _se.sizing));
        } else if ($(window).width() <= 1824 && $(window).width() > 1366) {
          sizingMethod(src, _se.regex, currentWidth, newWidth, newSrc, Math.round(1366 / _se.sizing));
        } else if ($(window).width() <= 1366 && $(window).width() > 767) {
          sizingMethod(src, _se.regex, currentWidth, newWidth, newSrc, Math.round(767 / _se.sizing));
        } else if ($(window).width() <= 767 && $(window).width() > 480) {
          sizingMethod(src, _se.regex, currentWidth, newWidth, newSrc, Math.round(480 / _se.sizing));
        } else if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
          sizingMethod(src, _se.regex, currentWidth, newWidth, newSrc, Math.round(250 / _se.sizing));
        }

        $el.attr(_se.methodName, newSrc.src);
      },

      sizingMethod = function(sSrc, sRegex, sCurrentW, sNewW, sNewSrc, sNewWidth) {

        sCurrentW = sSrc.match(sRegex);
        sNewW = 'wid=' + sNewWidth;
        sNewSrc.src = sSrc.replace(sCurrentW, sNewW);
        textWidth = sNewW.replace('wid=', '');

      },

      init = function() {
        for (i = 0; i < $el.size(); i++) {
          //console.log($el.text());
          resizeMethod();
        }
      };

    init();
    return $el;
  }
})(jQuery);

$(window).resize(function() {
  console.log('resizing');
  $('.testClass').resizeImage();
  $('.testClassTwo').resizeImage();
});
```

```css
a {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://testing1.com/maintest?wid=300" class="testClass">Testing</a>
<a href="http://testing2.com/maintest?wid=300" class="testClass">TestingTwo</a>
<a href="http://testing3.com/maintest?wid=400" class="testClassTwo">TestingThree</a>
<a href="http://testing4.com/maintest?wid=300" class="testClassTwo">TestingFour</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code of your plugin, it seems you need to provide an object with property named `methodName` and value of `href` to method `resizeImage()`:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    console.log('resizing');
    $('.testClass').resizeImage({methodName:'href'});
    $('.testClassTwo').resizeImage({methodName:'href'});
});
```

Comment: Welldone - good catch. method was actually made for Images not Hrefs